# How to unit test HBase in Spark streaming scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I was trying to unit test `doSomethingRdd` which requires to read some reference data from HBase in rdd transformation.

```
def doSomethingRdd(in: DStream[String]): DStream[String] = {
    in.map(i => {
        val cell = HbaseUtil.getCell("myTable", "myRowKey", "myFamily", "myColumn") 
        i + cell.getOrElse("")
    })
}

Object HBaseUtil {
    def getCell(tableName: String, rowKey: String, columnFamily: String, column: String): Option[String] = {
    val HBaseConn = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    //the rest of the code will use HBaseConn 
    //to get a HBase cell and convert to a string
    }
}
```

I read this [Cloudera article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-test-hbase-applications-using-popular-tools/) but I have some problem with their recommended methods.

This first thing I tried was using ScalaMock to mock `HBaseUtil.getUtil` method so I can bypass HBase connection. I also did some workaround in order to mock Object singleton suggested by this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702237/how-can-i-use-mockitosugar-to-mock-an-object-singleton-method?answertab=votes#tab-top). I updated my code a bit like below. However, `doSomethingRdd` failed because mocked hbaseUtil is not serialization which also explained by Paul Butcher in his [reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/7t7MVNzGUTQ)

```
def doSomethingRdd(in: DStream[String], hbaseUtil: HBaseUtilBody:HBaseUtil): DStream[String] = {
    in.map(i => {
        val cell = HbaseUtil.getCell("myTable", "myRowKey", "myFamily", "myColumn") 
        i + cell.getOrElse("")
    })
}

trait HBaseUtilBody {
    def getCell(tableName: String, rowKey: String, columnFamily: String, column: String): Option[String] = {
    val HBaseConn = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    //the rest of the code will use HBaseConn 
    //to get a HBase cell and convert to a string
    }
}

object HBaseUtil extends HBaseUtilBody
```

I think getting data from HBase in RDD transformation would be a very common pattern. But I'm not sure how to unit test it without connecting to a real HBase instance.

Comment: I ended up creating my own mock class.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 with HBase 2.x we use the `hbase-testing-util`. Simply add it to your SBT build file

> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-testing-util
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-testing-util" % "2.2.3" % Test

And then establish a connection like this

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility

val utility = new HBaseTestingUtiliy
utility.startMiniCluster() // defaults to 1 master, 1 region server and 1 data node
val connection = utility.getConnection()
```

Starting the MiniCluster actually starts

- MiniDFSCluster
- MiniZKCluster, and
- MiniHBaseCluster

In case you need to add some specific configuration (e.g. security settings) you can add hbase-site.xml to your resources.

For more information refer to section Integration Testing with an HBase Mini-Cluster in [HBase Reference Guide](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_integration_testing_with_an_hbase_mini_cluster).